# AngularJS ng-options from CakePHP Data

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some json data I receive from a cakePHP server. this is a snippet of what is found in my current `$scope.catalog.ConstructionMethod` ...

```
[
  {
    "ConstructionMethod": {
      "id": "99",
      "title": "All Plywood",
      "price": "0.12"
    }
  },
  {
    "ConstructionMethod": {
      "id": "139",
      "title": "Plywood Sides",
      "price": "0.05"
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to create a select box like so...

```
<select ng-model="Project.ConstructionMethod" ng-options=" ... ">
```

I have tried the following with no success ...

```
ng-options="item.title as item.ConstructionMethod for item in catalog.ConstructionMethod"

ng-options="item.ConstructionMethod.title for item in catalog.ConstructionMethod"
```

I am able to iterate through using `ng-repeat` just fine. :s

```
<p ng-repeat="item in catalog.ConstructionMethod">item.ConstructionMethod.title</p>
```

Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated... Thank you.

Comment: i would try ng-options="item.ConstructionMethod.name as item.ConstructionMethod.id for item in catalog"

Comment: Here is a codepen (very simplified) I just can figure it out :s http://codepen.io/ryanyakich/pen/jEzrqR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expounding on *aleberguer's* answer (which pointed out I needed a model) – I was still having a hard time having the correct options selected when staring my app. The whole "using select as and track by don't work together" thing... so this solution not only populated the options but enabled them to be selected when opening the app.

```
<select ng-model="result" ng-options="item.ConstructionMethod.title for (k, item) in catalog.ConstructionMethod track by item.ConstructionMethod.id"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular's select requires an ng-model to work.

Try with the following code:

```
<select ng-model="result" ng-options="item.ConstructionMethod as item.ConstructionMethod.title for item in catalog.ConstructionMethod"></select>
```

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: That solved the problem. I appreciate the answer! I feel s-m-r-t... thanks again.